# Parameterized JUnit tests lazy collection

Tags: java, junit4

I am writing a `parameterized` JUnit 4 test with about 100k instance of the parameters and I want to return a collection from the data method, that loads things lazily. But I get a class cast exception after I return my implementation of `java.util.Collection` saying my collection `cannot be cast to java.util.List`. Do I need to implement `List<Object[]>` instead of `Collection<Object[]>` even though `@Parameters` annotated method wants to return `Collection<Object[]>`?

Comment: "return" from what?  Your data() method? Why are you casting to a list; do you need an ordered collection?  Whatever you're doing isn't returning a List<Object[]>. You can always create a list out of the collection which is returned from data(), if you need to order it somehow, but I can't imagine why you'd want to do that, unless you have a pretty exotic test scenario. In fact, it's not clear to my why you'd ever investigate the return value from data(), unless you're testing the test.

Comment: Yes, return from `data()` method. I am not doing the casting to a `List`. Seems like Junit is casting the `Collection<Object[]>` returned from the `data()` method to `List<Object[]>`. All I want is to return my implementation of `Collection` so I can return the elements lazily instead of constructing all of them at once and returning that.

Comment: I have a similar need - my parameter sets are calculated externally and become available lazily, so I want to start running my first test as soon as the first parameters set is available, and then block while the next is prepared. However, @Parameters tries to drain the data() iterable before it starts the first test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, since you haven't provided any code to go on, that Hibernate is probably returning List<Object>, not List<Object[]>.  In the body of your data() method, iterate over the Hibernate return collection and insert the objects into an object array, then collect those and return them.

```
List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (Object obj : hibernateReturnCollection) {
    Object[] element = new Object[1];
    element[0] = obj;
    result.append(element);
}
return result;
```